# Force the whole website use one font -family

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to apply

font-family: Helvetica to all element in the site.

So I write

```
body, html {
    font-family: Helvetica !important;
}
```

in the CSS file, the problem is , the font-family is still override by other inner CSS. How to force the whole site use one font family?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Do not override them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it being overriden by other css style rules with `!important`? If so, there is nothing to do as more specific selectors win over more general ones.

Comment: @user782104 I think that's impossible. Show us the style on the element that is not using the font you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
* {
    font-family: Helvetica !important;
}
```

Comment: why? he say "All element"

Comment: what he is doing works too, the problem is that he is using !important again

Comment: media query? how do you know he is using media queries? I removed the -1 because it is important for you but this is not a valid answer

Comment: "media query? how do you know he is using media queries? "  -> " the font-family is still override by other inner CSS"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries maybe you need to know what is a media query

Comment: ohhh men!  if he have a media query with " html, body" modification for different screen, nooooo?

Comment: no, `html, body` is not a media query it is just a css selector, it becomes a media query when you use `@media()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the inspector in chrome, or other browser's equivalent to see how the cascade styles on your particular element unfolds. Your inner CSS could have also defined the !important flag, which overrides you definition on body.

If you post your entire html and CSS people might be able to help more easily.